# Pyinstaller Import Issues with Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, pyinstaller

There are a couple post in regards to Pyinstaller having issuing recognizing jinja2, unfortunately none have resolved my issue. Ideally if Pyinstaller supports a package which it states has support for jinja2 its hook should retrieve the package and its files.

I receive the following error when I run the built program:
**ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'Jinja2' . DataFrame.style requires jinja2. Use pip or conda to install Jinja2.**

[image]

From build log:

**30562 INFO: Processing module hooks...
30563 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'd:\mainapplicationfolder\venv\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...**


**I have tried the following under Windows 10, Python 3.8.5 with pyinstaller - 4.1, jinja2 - 2.11.2:**

**1**. --path "venv\Lib\site-packages"  (Path to my python packages, Pyinstaller builds several packages but ignores jinja2)

**2**. --hidden-import="jinja2" (no effect)

**3**. --path "D:\mainapplicationfolder\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\lexer.py" (To test to see if it will build one single file, no luck)

**4**. manually created a spec file and added gmas80s's script to add the exact path of each file (no effect)

My program directory tree is as follows:


**mainapplicationfolder**
**-**makespec.py
**-**main.py
**-**functions (folder)
**-**images (folder)
**-**venv (folder)
**--**Lib
**---**site-packages 
**----**jinja2
**-**32_32_gQU_icon.ico

**Example of my spec folder:**

```py
# -*- mode: python -*-

# <<< START ADDED PART    
from PyInstaller.building.build_main import Analysis, PYZ, EXE, COLLECT, BUNDLE, TOC


def collect_pkg_data(package, include_py_files=False, subdir=None):
    import os
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import get_package_paths, remove_prefix, PY_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS

    # Accept only strings as packages.
    if type(package) is not str:
        raise ValueError

    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths(package)
    if subdir:
        pkg_dir = os.path.join(pkg_dir, subdir)
    # Walk through all file in the given package, looking for data files.
    data_toc = TOC()
    for dir_path, dir_names, files in os.walk(pkg_dir):
        for f in files:
            extension = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
            if include_py_files or (extension not in PY_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS):
                source_file = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
                dest_folder = remove_prefix(dir_path, os.path.dirname(pkg_base) + os.sep)
                dest_file = os.path.join(dest_folder, f)
                data_toc.append((dest_file, source_file, 'DATA'))

    return data_toc

pkg_data = collect_pkg_data('jinja2')  # <<< Put the name of your package here
# <<< END ADDED PART    

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['makespec.py'],
             pathex=['venv\\Lib\\site-packages', 'venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\jinga2', 'D:\\mainapplicationfolder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('functions\\*', 'functions'), ('images\\*', 'images')],
             hiddenimports=['jinja2'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='myprogram',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='32_32_gQU_icon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               pkg_data,  # <<< Add here the collected files
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='makespec')
```

The program builds and seems to pull in all the other packages except Jinja2 even after all the files are specified. It seems many others have successfully navigated this issue. I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Please edit into your question the _full_ error message you get when you run your program.

Comment: Updated with error info

Comment: Additional update with screen shot of error console when I execute built program

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found it wasn't the jinja2 package but its dependency on markupsafe.  The markupsafe package was updated and it broke 'soft_unicode'.  You can see the github thread here: https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/issues/284

Try this version in your requirements.txt or pip.

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Best of luck.